# UIRefreshControl Exact Content offset trigger height

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, uicontrol, uirefreshcontrol

What is the exact contentoffset that will trigger a uirefreshcontrol? Doing my own testing with debug messages it seems to fluctuate around +-100 px, but I would like to know the exact number. Does anybody have some insight into this matter? Thanks

Comment: Mine is around 200. It may varies in different case. I also want to know the exact value or if there is a way to get the value programatically?

Answer (score 0):

You can print the value of `Tableview.ContentOffset.Y` in the refresh selector call. This is your trigger point.